# Answer given to a closed question

Tags: bug, closed-questions

In this [closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26164258/601179), an answer was given several seconds after I marked it as duplicated (with my gold badge).

I closed it in: `2014-10-02 15:33:31Z`
The answer was posted in: `2014-10-02 15:34:30Z`

Is this a bug?

Comment: I have seen this a couple of times as well.

Comment: @FelixKling, it looks like someone in SE was doing only client side validation...

Comment: I thought someone who knows the details better than I do would have provided some comment or answer already. It is *known* that the system allows posting answers after a question has been closed. I've done it. I had to circumvent the UI. I believe there is a grace period, after which it won't work. Perhaps you also need to already have a draft already known to the system before the question gets closed. I've done it once or twice and did not pay too much attention to the criteria that are required for it to work. Not a bug. More of an awkward feature.

Comment: @Louis as the saying goes "there ain't no bugs in software developments, only undocumented features"

Comment: @Louis Oded's answer on the dup is exactly the answer.  The server will accept an answer during the grace period.  It used to be several hours, but not sure exactly how long (and if it is still hours long).  However, client side, users are prohibited from attempting to post the answer as soon as the client is notified that the question was close.  Ergo... if the client isn't notified (or misses the notification) then the user can still submit the answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yeah, I misremembered a possible requirement that a draft be known to the system. Circumventing the UI is equivalent to a missed notification, by the way. Or at least it used to be. The times I did it, the button for adding answers had been disabled but I posted anyway after poking around in the DOM.

Comment: @Louis correct, that can be done (I intentionally didn't mention that work around to limit abuse)